# While loop output one digit per loop at the same position

Tags: php

```
 echo "counter: ";
 $i=1;
 while ($i <= 5) {
    print($i);
    sleep(1);
    $i++;
 }
```

The above will output: counter: 12345 I need to output eg.: loop 3 - counter: 3 (one digit per loop)

How to do it:

1) When running in a browser?

2) When running from command line (php index.php)?

Comment: What is difference of your loop and counter? Can you explain more detailed please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you asking for to explain. This is just an example of while loop.

Comment: You need to use java-script at browser, to update any div in 1st iteration  `counter: 1` 2nd iteration  `counter: 2` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to make an auto-updated string. It's impossible to make it with only PHP. You should use Javascript (or a library like jQuery) and send the data from PHP via Ajax call.

You can even do this only with Javascript.

```
var counter = 1;
setInterval(function () {
  counter++;
}, 5);
```

For command line you can use your code with "\r" at the end of the string.

```
$i=0;
while ($i <= 5) {
   sleep(1);
   $i++;
   echo "counter: $i\r";
}
```

Comment: well, I want to do a few operations on database in one loop, so this should be as simple it can be. What would be the answer for question 2?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. The counter string was brought inside the loop and a break was added for a new line simulation. Also the < was changed to <= as the loop was running for 4 times instead of 1.

```
 $i=1;
 while ($i <= 5) {
 print("counter: $i <br>");
 sleep(1);
 $i++;
 }
```

Comment: No this not what I expect. I need to see one digit on the screen at the time. So counter: 3 if it is loop 3 (no more digits). It should like clear old digit every loop.